# Kundera Mongodb nearby places

Tags: mongodb, kundera

I want to execute below mongodb query using kundera

```
 db.storemaster.find( { loc: { $near : {$geometry: { type: \"Point\",  coordinates: [ 78.35249829999998, 17.4613602 ] }, $maxDistance: 5000 } }})
```

Help me..

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using ?

```
String execScript = "db.storemaster.find( { loc: { $near : {$geometry: { type: \"Point\",  coordinates: [ 78.35249829999998, 17.4613602 ] }, $maxDistance: 5000 } }}).toArray()";

Object result = (client).executeScript(execScript);
```

Chhavi

Comment: Native query support coming with next Kundera release should simplify this.